# Worksheet names cannot be empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I am getting the error `Worksheet names cannot be empty` while downloading Data in Excel document. Below is my Code from where i am getting error

```
protected void btnDownloadExcel_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        DataTable dt = GetReportData();
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            string fileName = drpReports.SelectedItem.ToString();
            using (XLWorkbook excel = new XLWorkbook())
            {
                //error from below line
                excel.Worksheets.Add(dt);
                excel.Style.Alignment.Horizontal = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Center;
                excel.Style.Font.Bold = true;
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName + ".xlsx");

                using (var myMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    excel.SaveAs(myMemoryStream);
                    myMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
                    Response.Flush();
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "err_msg", "<script language='javascript'>alert('No records found. Please check the selection criteria.');</script>", false);

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "err_msg", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Oops..!! some error occured. Please contact to administrator.');</script>", false);
        log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["loginid"] = LoggedInUserDetails.LoginId.ToString();
        Log.Error(ex.Message, ex);
    }

}
```

I am getting error at `excel.Worksheets.Add(dt);` while adding my `Datatable` to excel. Can someone tell me where i am doing wrong.

Comment: You simply need to set `DataTable.TableName` property to something, which will become the name of sheet.

Comment: I already did setting the Datatable table name, still, has errors

Comment: Add     YourDataTableName.TableName = "Enter_a_Name_same_as_Excelsheetname";   Before Declaring your 
  XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected void btnDownloadExcel_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            DataTable dt = GetReportData();
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                string fileName = drpReports.SelectedItem.ToString();
                string attachment = "attachment;filename=" + fileName + ' ' + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + ".xlsx";
                Response.ClearContent();
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                string tab = "";
                foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
                {
                    Response.Write(tab + dc.ColumnName);
                    tab = "\t";
                }
                Response.Write("\n");
                int i;
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    tab = "";
                    for (i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
                    {
                        Response.Write(tab + dr[i].ToString());
                        tab = "\t";
                    }
                    Response.Write("\n");
                }
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush(); // Sends all currently buffered output to the client.
                HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressContent = true;  // Gets or sets a value indicating whether to send HTTP content to the client.
                HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest(); // Causes ASP.NET to bypass all events and filtering in the HTTP pipeline chain of execution and directly execute the EndRequest event.

            }


            else
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "err_msg", "<script language='javascript'>alert('No records found. Please check the selection criteria.');</script>", false);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "err_msg", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Oops..!! some error occured. Please contact to administrator.');</script>", false);
            log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["loginid"] = LoggedInUserDetails.LoginId.ToString();
            Log.Error(ex.Message, ex);
        }

    }
```

Comment: should it be  Response.ContentType ="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"; ? I tried using that MIME type and it says the file is corrupted

Answer (score 3):

Add

```
YourDataTableName.TableName = "Enter_a_Name_same_as_Excelsheetname";
```

Before declaring your

```
XLWorkbook excel= new XLWorkbook()
```

or

```
 var ws= excel.Worksheets.Add(table);    
 ws.Name="Enter_a_Name_same_as_Excelsheetname";
```

Comment: Thank you for simple and correct solution.

Answer (score 2):

I am able to see the mentioned issue while trying to add a DataTable without table name. When i tried with a DataTable with table name, it worked fine. In this case, the DataTable name will be preserved as the name of worksheet.

```
using ClosedXML.Excel;
using System;
using System.Data;

namespace ClosedXML_Test
{
class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This example method generates a DataTable.
    /// </summary>
    static DataTable GetTable()
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable("Test");//DataTable with name - works fine
        //DataTable table = new DataTable("Test"); //DataTable without name - issue reproduced as you mentioned
        table.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("Drug", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Patient", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));

        // Here we add five DataRows.
        table.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", "David", DateTime.Now);
        table.Rows.Add(50, "Enebrel", "Sam", DateTime.Now);
        table.Rows.Add(10, "Hydralazine", "Christoff", DateTime.Now);
        table.Rows.Add(21, "Combivent", "Janet", DateTime.Now);
        table.Rows.Add(100, "Dilantin", "Melanie", DateTime.Now);
        return table;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var workbook = new XLWorkbook();
        var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add(GetTable());
        workbook.SaveAs("Sample.xlsx");
        workbook.Dispose();

        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Sample.xlsx");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: i tried this, it prompts an error "Access to the path 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\Sample.xlsx' is denied."

Comment: @Juran check my answer

Comment: i used @vijayakumar answer but i should run as administrator with Visual studio